# Redirect http request to https (spray io/scala)

Tags: scala, spray

How do I redirect my `http` requests to `https`? Though this has been a common question, I don't see any solution for `spray io`.

- I have enabled ssl using Apache `CamelSslConfiguration` which works just fine.
- I have setup port forwarding (iptables) from 80 -> 8081 and 443 -> 8081

Below is my Boot.scala file

```
object Boot extends App with CamelSslConfiguration with ApiScheduler {

  // we need an ActorSystem to host our application in
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("on-spray-can")

  // create and start our service actor
  val service = system.actorOf(Props[ApiServiceActor], "api-service")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(50.seconds)
  // start a new HTTP server on port 8080 with our service actor as the handler
  IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8081)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working with help from Spray IO google group.

I have summed up everything at [Http to Https Redirect](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/57TJ3q8Mx3I)